# android scan for wifi network

Tags: android, wifi

i am trying out this code for scanning wifi networks but getting null pointer exception not sure what problem i registered all permission in manifest.

```
IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
    i.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i(TAG, "opening wifimanager");
                WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                mWifiManager.getScanResults();

            }
        }
    ,i);



        mWifiManager.startScan();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing this on a device or on a stimulator. And have you added the following permissions on your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: On a stimulator I am sure ! :D